# AngularJS - No encuentra controlador API

Tags: angularjs, .net, api, controller

Colegas, tengo el siguiente problema: al querer acceder desde un controller js hacia un API controller sólo para traer una lista de usuarios, la consola me lanza el error 404.

Servicio que accede al controlador correspondiente pasando como parámetro el nombre del mismo (apiName)

```
cobra.app.factory('ResourceService', function ($resource) {
var prefix = '/FLOTA/api/';

function _getResource(apiName) {
    var idParam = (apiName.indexOf(":id") >= 0 ? "" : "/:id");
    var resource = $resource(apiName + idParam, { id: '@id' },
    {
        queryp: { method: 'PUT' },
        update: { method: 'PUT' },
        save: { method: 'POST', params: { id: null } },
        getp: { method: 'POST', params: { id: null } }
    });
    return resource;
}

function getResource(apiName) {
    return _getResource(prefix + apiName);
}

return {
    resource: getResource
}
});
```

Al Indicarle que acceda al controlador API "Users" es donde lanza el 404

```
cobra.app.controller('usersListController', function ($scope, LoadingService, UtilityService, ResourceService, NotificationService) {
$scope.collection = [];
$scope.displayedCollecion = [];
$scope.headers = {
    username: { name: 'Usuario', visible: true },
    fullname: { name: 'Nombre', visible: true }
};

var restAPI = ResourceService.resource('Users');

var errorCallback = function (result) {
    LoadingService.hideLoading();
    NotificationService.error(result);
}

var successGetCallback = function (result) {
    $scope.collection = result;
    $scope.displayedCollecion = [].concat(result);

    LoadingService.hideLoading();
}

var getCollection = function () {
    restAPI.query(successGetCallback, errorCallback);
}

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    getCollection();
});
});
```

Cualquier orientación se agradece!

Comment: Hola Paulo, bienvenido. Por favor, sustituye las imagenes por texto. Puedes formatear el codigo seleccionandolo y pulsando `ctrl + k` o pulsando en el icono `{}`. Muchas gracias y un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Un posible error puede ser que que cuando mandas la URL al servicio $resources lo haces solo parcialmente (“*/FLOTA/api/Users*") por lo tanto si estás en “*www.tudominio.com*” el request lo va a hacer a la URL “*www.tudominio.com/FLOTA/api/Users*”, podrías probar poniendo la URL completa para asegurarte de que está llegando a la dirección correcta.

También veo que la función query que es la que estás usando la estás haciendo como **PUT** cuando un request que intenta obtener una lista y en la que no se envía un payload normalmente debería de ser **GET** pero eso depende de como está diseñado el API que estás consumiendo. Asegúrate de que estás usando el método correcto.

Espero te sea de ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Ya había probado el mandar la ruta completa por parámetro pero sigue dando el mismo error. Y por temas de implementación, query debe ir con PUT. Se agradece la ayuda de todas formas amigo!